# create an ad-hoc mobile network using wifi-direct

Tags: android, adhoc, wifi-direct

I have a project idea which is suggested by my lecturer to create an ad-hoc mobile network using WiFi-direct available in android mobile phones. the purpose of this network is to send data over a long distance from one android device to another using several other android devices as intermediate nodes and also to use a MANET routing protocol for path selection when there's more than one path available to reach the destination. 
I have looked into some of the questions related to this where some have asked how to implement a similar type of network but most of those answers were pretty old at which time WiFi-direct was not available widely, as I assume. 
I'm pretty much new to android and I'm learning it now for this purpose. so I would like to know weather this can be done using an android app, some guidelines to start if possible and any sample codes i can refer to get this done.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's up with this awesome question not getting upvoted? The general cluelessness of the population insisting that it be hand-fed at any expense to privacy and security?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use socket server and socket client technology to share data between devices in the same network which is definitely not a long distance thing. For long distance, you have to use internet to send and receive data because socket servers/clients cant connect devices in other networks. I am not sure how its gonna work but Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the reply! but what i meant from long distance is reaching to destination node through several other intermediate nodes. as an example, D being the destination node, sending data from A to B then B to C and finally D where B and C will act as intermediate nodes. also B and C should be able to handle one-to-many connections for simultaneous communication.

Comment: If node A and D are in the same network then why would you want to use B and C, just connect them directly. If i am not wrong, you are trying to do what routers does in networking.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention they are not in the same network. A and B, B and C, C and D are 3 different networks.

Comment: "The ad hoc networking technology operating on Wi-Fi ad hoc mode, at the unlicensed ISM band of 2.4 GHz may result in profit loss by cellular carriers since ISM band is free and unlicensed while cellular carriers operate on licensed band at 900 MHz, 1200 MHz, 1800 MHz, etc. This has the potential to threaten telecommunication operators (telcos). Smart phone mobile ad hoc networks can operate independently and allow communications among smart phones users without the need for any 3G or 4G LTE signals to be present..." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_phone_ad_hoc_network